# remote desktop ubuntu server

Tags: windows, remote-desktop, x-windows, ubuntu-server

I was wondering if it's possible to remote desktop to an ubuntu server that contain no xwindows (text only) from Windows. To put it in another word, I want to full desktop GUI of ubuntu server on my Windows machine. If it's possible, what are the step into making this possible.

Thanks

Comment: You want a GUI Interface from Windows on an Ubuntu Server that has no GUI?

Comment: Maybe you can explain what you want to get from this and why ssh is inadequate. Do you mean the ubuntu console in this case, as there is no gui.

Comment: Putty will work if all you want to do is see your "console" and have control of the server from the given cli. As far as a full gui, that won't really be possible on a server with no gui.

Comment: I'm not very proficient in using console via SSH, I feel better when I can have the KDE desktop environment.

Comment: @chmod But KDE is not text only, and you explicitly asked for *text only*.

Comment: @chmod: You can install KDE by executing `sudo apt-get install --no-install-recommends kubuntu-desktop`. Then all you need is a VNC server. But I would advice against it. With time, you'll get used to SSH.

Answer (score 1):

You can't get remote desktop if contain no xwindows (text only), but you can use mobaxTerm for example to ssh to that machine and when launch an application - it will popup on the screen of Windows client